# How to overlay one jpeg image on top of another?

Tags: python, jpeg, rgb

So I have a project where I need to make some filters for photos using python. It's been easy so far, just making a B&W filter, an extra-blue filter, stuff like that.

But what if I could overlay another photo on top? Like having a translucent rain effect, or even a vignette?

If someone knows how to properly modify a photo at the pixel level that could give the effect of an overlapped filter? Even just naming a concept would help, thanks!

(It might also be impossible but that's ok)

Comment: How are you making a black and white filter?

Comment: @PeterWood just averaging rgb

Comment: @AkshaySehgal  actually it might. when i work on this later today ill look through it and see if i can make it work with jpg

Comment: but how are you working with `jpeg` images? Are you using a library like [tag:opencv] or [tag:pillow]?

Comment: The [Pillow fork](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) of the PIL (Python Imaging Library), has an [`alpha_composite()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite) function that can probably do it.